# Pattern is not splitting as desired, fails to split by +

Tags: java, regex, rpn

I have the following code :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(\\s\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)*\\s*[-\\+\\*/\\$£]");

String input = "4.0 5.0 2.0 / + 7.0 - 11.0 34.0 2.0 / 3.0 / 1.0 * +";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    output.add(matcher.group());
}
```

The pattern that is compiled has gone through  a number of iterations, in it's current iteration it adds to the list the following :

```
[4.0 5.0 2.0 /, 7.0 -, 11.0 34.0 2.0 /, 3.0 /, 1.0 *]
```

It should be splitting by all operations and keeping the operations in the split string so i would have expected the following output:

```
[4.0 5.0 2.0 /,+, 7.0 -, 11.0 34.0 2.0 /, 3.0 /, 1.0 *, +]
```

It looks to be that is not splitting when it only finds an operator and not a number.

So essentially i would like the current behaviour as well as it splitting operators such that if it finds 2 operators in a row it splits them up. such that the following:

```
2 2 + / 3 +
```

would equal

```
[2 2 +, /, 3 +]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*)?\s*[-+*/$£])
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV9zH7/1)

In Java it would be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile
  ( "((?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s+\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)*)?\\s*[-+*/$£])" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but from what you describe, I don't see why it needs to be so complicated. `"[\\d. ]+?[-+/*£$]"` seems to do exactly what you want.